# Change Label Visible attritube

Tags: xamarin

Two Content Page Page1 with Page2,Page2 have a Label.
Can you tell me how to change Page2 Lable IsVisible attribute from Page1.xaml.cs
I try to change Page1.xaml.cs static variable and add below code at Page2.xaml.cs

```
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if(StaticVarFromPage1=="1")
            fix.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

Is there other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there other way to do it?

There are several methods we can use to achieve this.

### Method 1:

The Best option would be to use data binding and update a global model with the proper value to achieve this.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a global class

```
public static class SharedData 
{
    public static int MyTestData ="0";

}
```

2.then you can change the global variable `MyTestData` everywhere. For example, you can change the value on the first page as follows:

```
       private void SetGlobalButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        SharedData.MyTestData = "updated string";

    }
```

3.On the second page, you can get the value as follows:

```
        protected override void OnAppearing() 
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        string data = SharedData.MyTestData;

        //here you can change Label Visible attritube based on the passed data
    }
```

**Note:**

However, if page one and page two use the same view model, then just make sure you use the same instance of the view model for page 1 and page 2 as necessary.

### Method 2:

Another common approach is to use `EventHandler`.

You can define `EventHandler` on the `SecondPage`,just as follows:

```
public static EventHandler<string> mEventHandler; // define a static  EventHandle
```

Then you can pass your data with the following code:

```
   private void PassDataButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        EventHandler<string> handler = mEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            myValue = "1";
            mEventHandler(this, myValue);

            Navigation.PopAsync();

        }
    }
```

On the first Page, you need to add the following code in the constructor of `FirstPage` :

```
           SecondPage.mEventHandler += delegate (object s, string a)
        {
            BackCall(s, a);
        };
```

And the code of function `BackCall` on `FirstPage` is:

```
    private void BackCall(object s, string a)
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(a));
        }
        else
        {

            DisplayAlert("Alert", "The call back value is : " + a, "OK");

        //here you can change Label Visible attritube based on the passed data

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you anser me immediate. Detail so complet,code clean,I think you spend a long time. Thank you again.